# Android SQL Blob

Tags: android, database, sqlite, blob, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to store and array of bytes (byte[]) into a DB.  I have the array of bytes, a content provider and a database.  When I try to insert into the Blob the insert returns -1.  Can somebody show me how to get this done.

**Insert**

```
byte[] inData = nw.receive();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(InDatabase.Columns.DATA, inData);
values.put(InDatabase.Columns.SIZE, inData.length);
NetService.this.getContentResolver().insert(InContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

**Content Provider**

```
mDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
Long rowId = mDB.insert(mDBHelper.tableName(), null, aValues);
```

**Database**

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { 
        db.execSQL("CREATE table " + TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, data BLOB, size INTEGER);"); 
}
```

Like I said If I don't put the `values.put(InDatabase.Columns.DATA, inData)`, it works perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the implementation was right, the problem was with the SQLiteDatabaseHelper.  I did not implement the onUpdate() method.  Because my database already existed on the device with a different layout (the BLOB field did not exist) the insert method failed.

A quick uninstall of the .apk fixed the problem.  I could also implement the onUpdate method so when the database version changes there is a table drop or update.

Comment: The other thing you could do is increment the database version you are passing to your DbHelper constructor so that Android will automatically call the onUpgrade() function of your helper. You can just drop your DB tables and call onCreate() again from there to automatically recreate everything. Just another option you have that makes development a bit easier.